# How do I choose a number out of a predefined matrix in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been attempting to code a bot for a client, but as I am self-taught, sometimes the easiest aspects escape me. I know that I have known how to do this before, but I need to fix the following code:

```
@client.command()
async def rroulette(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f"Aye, {ctx.author.mention}! Choose a number beween **1** and **6**! We all know what happens if your number is chosen, though, Comrade! ;)")
  rroulette1 = await client.wait_for("Message")
  await ctx.send("Alright, Comrade! Here goes nothing!")
  await asyncio.sleep(2)
  rroulette2 = (random.randint(1, 6))
  if rroulette2 == rroulette1.content:
    await ctx.send("Oops! The number was " + rroulette1.content + "! You know what that means!")
else:
  await ctx.send("Ah, you are safe, Comrade! The number was not yours.")
```

The bot always responds with the `else` function, that being that your number is never chosen. I do not know how to fix this.

The overall purpose of the code is, as you probably guessed, to play Russian roulette. If your number is chosen, you get muted for 5 minutes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `rroulette2 == int(rroulette1.content)`? I expect `rroulette1.content` is a string, and a string is never equal to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rroulette2 = (random.randint(1, 6))
if rroulette2 == int(rroulette1.content):
  await ctx.send("Oops! The number was " + rroulette1.content + "! You know what that means!")
else:
  await ctx.send("Ah, you are safe, Comrade! The number was not yours.")
```

As @Oli said, the content of `rroulette1` is always a string, you need to convert it to `int` and this should work